# End \verbatim command

Tags: environments, verbatim, code

The verbatim environment is used to display LaTeX commands instead of having them executed.

To display a single command in-line, the `\verb||` command can be used.

To display a whole block, we can use `\begin{verbatim}` to open the environment and `\end{verbatim}` to close it.

But I've come across `\verbatim` as well. With that, we can also type `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}` having them shown on our document and not initiating and ending their environment. The problem is, I still haven't found how to terminate it.

I know there are better ways, and maybe `\verbatim` should be never used at all. But I just wanted to understand how it worked to learn more about LaTeX. After invoking it, how can I return to a normal environment where LaTeX code is compiled, a normal font is used and line breaks are automatic?

Comment: The environment `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}` is essentially the same as `\bgroup\verbatim...\endverbatim\egroup`. That is, matching `\verbatim` and `\endverbatim` inside a group. Have a look at the documentation to the verbatim environment  (using `texdoc verbatim` on a unix-like system), to find out how to use it inside other environments

Comment: Btw, for displaying tex code in a document I recommend using the [listings package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings).

Comment: @Andrew: No, verbatim is rather special and you can't end it with `\endverbatim`.

Comment: In fact, Ulrike is right. I tried and even `\endverbatim` gets written. Not even with `\bgroup` and `\egroup` it has any effect. Thanks to you I'm learning a lot about it, but my quick question still stands: even if I simply shouldn't, after I simply type `\verbatim` and nothing else, how can I close the environment?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, didn't know this ( obviously! :)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\newcommand\foo` will **not** generate `\endfoo`. It's the `\end{foo}` which checks if `\endfoo` exists, and if it doesn't just inserts an `\endgroup` without worrying.

Comment: @Manuel: You're right. I confused it with some other setup

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`verbatim` is a very special environment which looks for the exact *string*  `\end{verbatim}` to end it. Unlike other latex environments you can't use `\env ...\endenv` instead of `\begin{env} ...\end{env}` with verbatim.

If you really want to start with  `\verbatim` then you must do something like this to get around the errors due to the various latex settings for environments in general and `verbatim` specially:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begingroup\makeatletter\def\@currenvir{verbatim}
\verbatim
  verbatim 
\end{verbatim}

text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Which shows that it is not a good idea to use `\verbatim` directly without the help of packages like verbatim.

Comment: Thanks for satisfying my curiosity! Searching for the meaning of every command you used I feel like I learned a lot! BTW, should I use `\makeatother` afterwards?

Comment: The `\makeatletter` is in a group, so `\makeatother` is not needed.

Comment: But there is an `\endverbatim` macro.  I use it when creating environments with definitions like `{...\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup \verbatim
}{\endverbatim%
\unskip\setbox0=\lastbox\egroup...}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Yes there is. But you can't use it to end the "verbatim" processing of `\verbatim`.

Answer (score 21):

Package `verbatim` supports the creation of own `verbatim` environment, see section 2.1 of the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/verbatim.pdf). The following example defines environment `metaverbatim` in order to allow `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}` inside the verbatim block:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newenvironment{metaverbatim}{\verbatim}{\endverbatim}

\begin{document}
\begin{metaverbatim}
\begin{verbatim}
  This is a verbatim block.
\end{verbatim}
\end{metaverbatim}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Internally `\verbatim` and `\endverbatim` are the commands that are executed as start and end part of the environment `verbatim`. But they should not be used outside an environment, because the `verbatim` environment specifically looks for `\end{...}` with `...` as the name of the verbatim environment.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great way to include `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}` inside a verbatim block!

Answer (score 14):

I suggest a look at the `fancyvrb` package, which introduces several customization facilities.

The main environment is called `Verbatim`, so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}
\begin{verbatim}
This is a verbatim block.
\end{verbatim}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

will work flawlessly. There's still a problem if you need to show an example of a `Verbatim` environment. If you do, then adding

```
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{MetaVerbatim}{Verbatim}{}
```

will allow

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{MetaVerbatim}
  {Verbatim}
  {formatcom=\color{mvcolor}}% this argument contains options   
\colorlet{mvcolor}{green!60!red}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}
\begin{verbatim}
This is a verbatim block.
\end{verbatim}
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{MetaVerbatim}
\begin{Verbatim}
This is a Verbatim block.
\end{Verbatim}
\end{MetaVerbatim}

\end{document}
```

The color of `MetaVerbatim` is just to show one of the many possible customizations.

[image]