# Use \(end)comment instead of \begin/\end{comment}

Tags: environments, verbatim, comments

In my document, the `comment` environment works fine, but `\comment` and `\endcomment` stop processing of what comes next in the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
X

\begin{comment}
1
\end{comment}

Y

\comment
2
\endcomment

Z
\end{document}
```

Why is that? Is that similar to [End \verbatim command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247404/end-verbatim-command)?

Comment: 'Yes': this is verbatim-like

Comment: ***Never*** use the `\foo...\endfoo` commands in the body of a document. ***Ever***. Is that clear? `;-)` You immediately get into troubles if you do, not only for this kind of verbatim-like environments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `comment` environment is defined by the `verbatim` package as a variant of `verbatim`: instead of printing each line, it simply throws it away.

The package defines its verbatim-like environments by doing some steps.

First all special characters (well, almost all) become non special; then TeX is instructed to absorb one line at a time, checking whether it contains the *string* `\end` (with a non-special backslash). If it does, a further check is done, to see whether it is followed by the *string* `{foo}`, where `foo` is the name the current environment. If this string is not found, the line is treated like the ones not containing `\end`. Otherwise, the line is thrown away and the verbatim-like environment is finished up, executing the *macro* `\endfoo` and closing the group started by `\begin{foo}`.

Thus, when seeing `\endcomment`, the line is recognized to contain `\end`, but no `{comment}` string follows, so TeX continues its work processing line by line until finding `\end{document}`, which *does* satisfy the requirements, because the current environment is indeed `document`.

---

As a general rule, *never* use `\foo...\endfoo` in the document body. You'll get into troubles. Just for an easy example, try

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\quote
Some text that should wrap around, let's type something long
enough. Hope this will suffice.
\endquote

\quote
Some text that should wrap around, let's type something long
enough. Hope this will suffice.
\endquote

\end{document}
```

Here's the (perhaps surprising) output:

[image]

Using `\foo` and `\endfoo` when *defining* environments is OK and, in some cases, mandatory. But use it with care.