# How can I convert a copied text to Latex Syntax?

Tags: texmaker

I want to copy and paste some terminal output into my Latex document. I am using texmaker and as soon as I try to compile text like this

> [trace]  ?- mutter_von(Mutter, Kind).
>      Call: (8) mutter_von(_4028, _4030) ? creep
>      Exit: (8) mutter_von(marie, hans) ? creep

texmaker gives me a compilation errors because of the symbols '_', '[' and ']'. Is there any convienient way to force paste the above text into a texmaker document and replace [ to $[$ for example. Or do I need to do that manually, because thats a huge pain.

Comment: You could write a shell script (or whichever language you prefer) that does the conversion. Or you paste this in a verbatim environment.

Comment: I'm doing it currently with the help of the replace function of any text editor. What do you mean by verbatim environment?

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247404/end-verbatim-command

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer But for your purposes, there are commands `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}` that you can enclose your text in.

Comment: @Davislor Ah thats sound great, thanks I ll try that!

Comment: How exactly do you want to use this text? Should it just be displayed like it is in the terminal? In that case `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}` should do (or any other verbatim environment, e.g. those provided by `listings`). Do you want to process this output further? In that case, writing a small parser shouldn't be too hard.