# How to get the desired output with proper alignment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings, algorithms, verbatim, alignment

How to write a c++ code in LaTeX  with proper alignment?

I am providing more details about my question below:
I need to write this:

```
if(a==b):
    a=2
    b=2
```

I need to write this above code in exactly the same way I put it above.
But if I use the following code in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    
    if(a==b):
        a=2
        b=2
      
\end{document}
```

I am not getting my required output. Can someone please help me out on how to get the desired output with proper alignment?

Answer (score 2):

The package [listings](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings) enables users to create many customized styles to insert code in TeX. Users can also insert code from external files or set any desired color scheme, for example [this](https://pt.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_listing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63073356/fontcolor-in-listing).

A MWE follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
if(a==b):
  a=2
  b=2
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
if(a==b):
  a=2
  b=2
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Notice the `if`is with bold when `language=C` is used.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the following:

```
\begin{verbatim}
if(a==b):
    a=2
    b=2
\end{verbatim}
```

Should give you the desired result.

**EDIT**

This is the result:

[image]

Verbatim is used to write code as is, ignoring commands etc. Have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247404/end-verbatim-command) or [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_listing) for further info.

Comment: But your code does not give the necessary alignment which I guess was the main query in the question

Comment: @Charlotte see edited answer with the result. Why is it not aligned? What exactly do you mean?